# Are there any banners or ads that I can use to promote this site on my site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Please let me know how I can do my part. If there is any way I can promote this site with ads, banners, etc I would be happ to add them to my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE doesn't make specifically branded banners or such until a site graduates and gets its own theme. Right now we'll have too make our own banners/ads.

You can find StackExchange's logo in a higher resolution [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos). Just be sure to follow their guidelines [outlined here](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

You can also find useful pieces of elevator pitch and such to describe the site on the [About page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/about).

You can see some ideas another beta site had with regards to a flyer to promote the site [here](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1259/56).

As an after thought, we could have sort of a contest where users could design ads and post them on a meta post (sort of like Photography.SE's weekly photo contest). Other users would vote for the ads they like.

Comment: This has also been done over on Anime.SE, once we get some moderation in place, it will be taken care of http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/364/community-promotion-ads-on-the-se-network

Answer (score 4):

You can get your user "flair" [on your profile](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/438/defor-mations/flair). It's an HTML anchor and image that updates regularly. You can use it to "show-off" your reputation and badge achievements.

Comment: Not sure this is what the OP is looking for

Comment: @Luke he could be. To advertise Blender.SE and his profile at the same time.

Comment: +1 I think flair is a very good alternative and i have it on my Blender blog :)